# pd.dataframe: how to count values of a variable and find probabilities

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, probability

Here is my data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['a1'] = ['ABC','ACC','BCC','ABC','ABC','ACC','BCC']
df1['b1'] = ['ACC','AAC','BAC','ACC','ACC','AAC','BAC']
df1['group'] = ['A1','A2','A1','A3','A2','A1','A1']
df1['names'] = ['n1','n2','n3','n4','n1','n3','n3']

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['a2'] = ['ACC','BCC','ABC']
df2['b2'] = ['AAC','BAC','ACC']
df2['types'] = ['t1','t2','t3']

DF = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['a1','b1'], right_on=['a2','b2'])

>>> DF.sort_values('group')
    a1   b1 group names   a2   b2 types
0  ABC  ACC    A1    n1  ABC  ACC    t3
4  ACC  AAC    A1    n3  ACC  AAC    t1
5  BCC  BAC    A1    n3  BCC  BAC    t2
6  BCC  BAC    A1    n3  BCC  BAC    t2
2  ABC  ACC    A2    n1  ABC  ACC    t3
3  ACC  AAC    A2    n2  ACC  AAC    t1
1  ABC  ACC    A3    n4  ABC  ACC    t3
```

I want to calculate the probability of each type occurring among the total occurring times (nrow of df) on each name and then, sum them for each group.

For example, for group `A1`:

```
for n1: 
P_1 = P(t1_n1)+P(t2_n1)+P(t3_n1) = 0+0+1/7 = 1/7
for n2: 
P_2 = P(t1_n2)+P(t2_n2)+P(t3_n2) = 0
for n3: 
P_3 = P(t1_n3)+P(t2_n3)+P(t3_n3) = 1/7+0+2/7 = 3/7
for n4:
P_4 = P(t1_n4)+P(t2_n4)+P(t3_n4) = 0 

P_total = P_1+P_2+P_3+P_4
```

Expected output:

```
   groups   P_n1   P_n2  P_n3   P_n4  P_total
0  A1        1/7     0     3/7    0   4/7
1  A2        ....
2  A3        
3  A4
```

how can I accomplish my goal without many loop functions, in an elegant way? Thanks

Comment: I'm confused on this probability computation. The sum of probabilities of all type values appear in each group is always going to be 1. Take group A1 name n3 (for example). That has two `t2` and one `t1` the total group length is three. Meaning the probability that a value is `t2` is 2/3 and the probability the value is `t1` is 1/3 the sum of these is 1. Even if including `t3` the probability is `0/3` and `x = x + 0` so there would be no difference.

Comment: Will you expand the probability calculation (by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69964805/edit))  into an actual computation using the numbers from the provided sample data to clarify the calculation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pd.crosstab with normalize=True :

```
pd.crosstab(DF['group'],DF['names'],normalize=True)

names        n1        n2        n3        n4
group                                        
A1     0.142857  0.000000  0.428571  0.000000
A2     0.142857  0.142857  0.000000  0.000000
A3     0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.142857
```

To get you the total etc:

```
pd.crosstab(DF['group'],DF['names'],normalize=True)\
.assign(total = lambda x : x.sum(axis=1)).reset_index()

names group        n1        n2        n3        n4     total
0        A1  0.142857  0.000000  0.428571  0.000000  0.571429
1        A2  0.142857  0.142857  0.000000  0.000000  0.285714
2        A3  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.142857  0.142857
```

Comment: Hi. I am wondering how does .crosstab know to find the frequency of  'type' without mentioning variable 'type'? Thanks~

Comment: From what I can see, the variable type is not used to calculate your probability. It doesn't matter what category 'types' hold

Comment: @Geinkehdsk this only works because in your example, for each group, each `ni` corresponds to a unique  `tj`. Therefore the probabilities `P_i` don't depend on the 'type' column. If your real case is different, to get the correct output  use `pd.crosstab(index=DF.group, columns=[DF.names, DF.types], normalize=True).sum(axis=1, level='names').assign(total = lambda x : x.sum(axis=1))`. StupidWolf I think you should edit the answer with this general solution.